# Mazda 3 passenger side control arm - move engine and transaxle slightly forward?

Tags: mazda-3, control-arm

I'm replacing the control arms on my 2008 Mazda 3 GT Sport.  On the right-hand side the AC compressor gets in the way of the forward bolt on the control arm.

To make room for the bolt the service manual says to remove the No. 1 engine mount centre bolt and "move the engine and transaxle slightly towards the front side of the vehicle."

How does one move the engine and transaxle slightly forward?  And then back into place?

Comment: Can you get a picture of what your talking about? You may just need to lift the engine with a jack and block of wood and use a pry bar to shift it back or forwards. Also do you mean compressor?

Comment: Yes, definitely meant compressor.. I'll be servicing the condenser at the same time too :)  What I've seen online are people loosening the No. 3 engine mount and using a jack to move the engine up an inch or two.  Thought I'd try following the manual, but I'm not sure how to move the engine forward.

Comment: You can use a pry bar or a ratchet strap on one of the engine lift points to move the engine around just be careful and don't pry on anything plastic or something that could easily bend/break like a pulley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up following the tip I found in a YouTube video - remove the bolts from the No.3 Engine Mount and raise the engine with a jack and piece of wood under the oil pan.  Worked just fine and the mount fell right back into place when I brought the engine back down.